# Longest common subsequence of a set of sequences

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, subsequences

There is as input a set of $m$ sequences of length $n$.

I thought it was pretty straightforward at first that the time complexity of *the algorithm provided below* is $O(m^2n^4)$ but then it occurred to me that the time taken depends on the length of a LCS such that the longer a LCS relative to the input length the shorter the computation.
The question I have is can you confirm that while the (measured) time taken does depend on the length of a LCS (inversely), that fact does not have an effect on the result of the O-analysis?

```
// Let there be m sequences of lenght n.

// Length of lcs of two sequences. Theta(n^2)
lcs_length(x, y)
// Edit distance of two sequences. Theta(n^2)
d(x, y) = |x| + |y| - 2*lcs_length(x, y)
// Edit distance (total) of y to all of X. Theta(mn^2)
d(X. y) = sum of d(x, y) for x in X

// Longest common subsequence of a set of sequences S. O(m^2n^4)
lcs(S)
    X <- copy of S
    while true
        if exists x in X: |x| = 0
            return ""
        if exists x in X: for all s in S: x is a subsequence of s
            return x
        for x in X
            d_min <- +infinity
            i_min <- +infinity
            for i in 1..|x|
                // Make a copy of x with the ith symbol removed:
                x_i <- x[0..i-1] + x[i+1...]
                // Compute the sum of edit distances to all of the original sequences:
                d_i <- d(S, x_i)
                if d_i < d_min
                    d_min <- d
                    i_min <- i
        X <- X difference { x }
        X <- X union { x[0..i_min-1] + x[i_min + 1...] }
```

Comment: Edited the question again. I am interested in the analysis of this specific algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple different ways to upper-bound the running time of an algorithm.

Saying that the running time of an algorithm is $O(m^2 n^4)$ is analogous to saying that the running time is at most $m^2 n^4$ (ok, $c \cdot m^2 n^4$, for some constant $c$).  The keyword there is "at most".  So, think of $O(\cdot)$ as more like $\le $ than like $=$.

I haven't tried to analyze the running time of your specific algorithm, but to make up some numbers, it is possible that the running time could simultaneously be $O(m^2 n^4)$ and it could also be true that the running time is (say) $O(m^2 \ell^4)$ where $\ell$ is the length of the longest subsequence.  I'm totally making up those figures -- don't take them too seriously, as I don't claim they are actually valid running times for your algorithm -- I am just saying that both claims are consistent, i.e., they could both be true, without contradicting each other.

It's analogous to the fact that we could have both $x \le 3$ and $x \le 4$ be true.  Or, we could have both $x \le c^2$ and $x \le d^3$ be true.

---

Side remark: I haven't looked at your algorithm closely, but it looks suspicious to me. I would be surprised if it is a correct solution for the longest common subsequence problem.

Comment: Ok. Given a common sequence of length _**l**_ the `while true` loop executes exactly _**n-l**_ times, where again _**n**_ is the length of an input sequence, because on each round of the loop one symbol will be deleted from each sequence in _**X**_, and also because the checks in the beginning will terminate the loop and return an answer as soon as a common subsequence is found.

Comment: And so m^2n^3*(n-l) _is_ O(m^2n^4) because (n-l) is O(n), it is just that the worst case happens when the length of the longest common subsequence is zero.

Comment: A comment on the side remark. In fact, I've collected a few inputs (so far by testing repeatedly with different parameters) where the length of the common sequence is less than the length of a known common sequence present in the input. This does not mean that it is not a good approximation algorithm as far as length of the produced common sequences is concerned. Much analysis is left to do on that issue though. Also it's an interesting question if the algorithm can be 'fixed' to work correctly on all inputs (and remain in the current time bounds), but that would be very surprising indeed.